# Postgresql Count Function Assistance

Tags: postgresql

In postgres table named "Transactions", I am trying to count the number of J-type transactions for each month.  The following is my query.

```
select to_char("Date", 'Mon/YYYY') as "Date",
sum(case when l_part LIKE 'J%' then count end) as "IDs"
  from (
         select left("Type",4)as l_part, count(*),"Date" from 
         "Transactions" group by "Date",l_part
        ) p group by "Date"

  order by min("Date");
```

However, several problems occur with my query.

1) The number counted accumulates, so that every month's count also adds in the total count in all the months that have come before.  However, I am just trying to count each month individually.

2) With this query, my output repeats some months (i.e., May 2015 my have 3 rows, 2 rows are empty, and 1 row has the actual count)

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the subselect at all. Try this:

```
SELECT
  to_char("Date", 'Mon/YYYY') AS d,
  count(*) AS "IDs"
FROM "Transactions"
WHERE "Type" LIKE 'J%'
GROUP BY d
```

Comment: I started to comment but I realized that I need to give more context in the original post, so I will repost in a different way.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think it simpler to do this without subquery:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', "Date"), count(*)
FROM "Transactions"
WHERE "Type" LIKE 'J%'
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', "Date");
```

**Edited:**

The `date_trunc('month', ...)` function truncates date to first day of its month ex. both `'2015-May-26'` and `'2015-May-09'` becomes `'2015-May-01'` etc.
I've used this function instead of `to_char` because it's my habit since grouping by `text` could be slower than grouping by `date`. Of course  it depends on size of `"Transactions"` table.

Comment: the date trunc isn't enough. OP is grouping by month/year

Comment: Ok, but I think it's not so important since my answer also  "count the number of J-type transactions for each month" and `date_trunc` is more natural for my in such a case.

Comment: The problem being that it doesn't retain the OP's group by logic so if your code was used it would output something quite different from the goal

Comment: @AlVaz: grouping by `date_trunc('month',...)` _will_ group by month/year and is essentially the same as your solution - it just uses the first day of each month for the output.

Comment: @AlVaz there's nowhere said that `to_char("Date", 'Mon/YYYY')` is desired output. There's possibility that [Piechartking](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4582346/piechartking) didn't know about `date_trunc` and use `string` groupping with `to_char` (which could by slower). In terms of logic my solution gives exacly the same result as yours. I doubt there's reason to downvote.